# Exporting patches as loader in x64dbg?

Tags: x64dbg

Is there a way to export modifications made in x64dbg as a separate executable file, which can be used to patch a desired executable file without detection?

The resulting file should function as a loader, automatically patching the desired modifications when the original executable is opened.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. This sounds like a great idea for a plugin for x64dbg. Perhaps you could write it ;) ... But I am not aware of this already existing. Perhaps others will chime in and have a ready-to-use solution on offer.